# "Unauthenticated" error on a route that is not protected

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-passport

Part of my application does not utilize standard user authentication, and lies outside the auth group in my routes file. I am using Laravel Passport, VueJS2, VueRouter. Laravel is serving two blade files; one for the authenticated part of the application, and the other for the non-authenticated part.

However, I find that when trying to access that part of the application, it still requires me to be authenticated (I get the 401: Unauthorized error).

I have looked through my configuration files, and I can't seem to figure out why this would be displayed.

My api.php file:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;


Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
// A lot of routes here...
});

// These should not be guarded
// This is the route that triggers the unauthenticated message
Route::post('authenticate', 'TestController@authenticate');
```

THe JS file that makes the request:

```
authenticateUser: function() {
    var data = {
        'id' : this.$route.params.id,
        'passcode' : this.state.password,
    };

    var that = this;

    axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: '/api/authenticate',
      withCredentials: true,
      data: data,
    }).then(function(response) {
        swal('Great!', 'You have been authenticated.', 'success');
        that.$router.push('/client/create/' + that.$route.params.id);
    }, function(error) {
        swal('Woah!', 'Wrong password, go away.', 'error');
    });
}
```

Here is my kernel.php file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
            \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CreateFreshApiToken::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'test.auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyTestAccess::class,
        'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'test.state' => \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyTestState::class,
    ];
}
```

Comment: after googling the problem it seems like the root of the problem is csrf token. try declaring the csrf token in the ajax request and tell us what happens

Comment: it is because api routes has a default "api" middleware set on the routeserviceprovider. see [this](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php).

Comment: flex - It is sending the token; I am using bootstrap.js file which is included in 5.3, that automatically attaches the CSRF token. 


@elegisandi That makes sense. Is there any way to exclude those particular routes from just the authentication bit of the api middleware?

Comment: if you dont want to add auth on your route, just use the web routes then - just to be consistent with the framework :)